# Can not understand the error code in ftputil

Tags: python, ftputil

I am new to ftputil module of python.I have 2 FTP accounts on my web server. while just trying it, i encountered two problems:
1. while logging into account 1, I can get into there successfully

```
host = ftputil.FTPHost('ftp.mysite.com', 'user1', 'passwd1')
```

But whenever I tried to logging into another account, it raises and error:

```
ftputil.ftp_error.PermanentError: 530 Login incorrect.
```

However, I have problems too whenever I successfully log on. I tried out to list the directories using following commands:

```
name=host.listdir(host.curdir)
```

but instead showing off the directories, it raises an error something kinda this:

```
    in _try_with_oserror
        raise FTPOSError(*exc.args)
    ftputil.ftp_error.FTPOSError: 110
    Debugging info: ftputil 2.4.1, Python 2.7.3 (linux2)
```

what is wrong with my coding?

Comment: ftputil isn't a standard library module, and it looks (based on the number of tags) like hardly anyone has heard of it; so a link would be helpful. Anyway, did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the standard [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) module?

```
from ftplib import FTP

try:
    ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com', 'user1', 'passwd1')
except ftplib.error_perm, msg:
    print 'Error: ', repr(msg)

try:
    ftp.dir()
except ftplib.error_perm, msg:
    print 'Error: ', repr(msg)
```

Comment: yeah it helped me but a bit step ahead, not completely. As point out in previous answer, ftputils is not a standard python library. So I got login into my account but now problems seems to be of connection timeout. That might be a slow internet connection on my side. BTW, thanks a ton for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try a more recent version of the ftputil module.

It may have had a bug according to [this](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/ticket/33).